# Is there any way to remove space to the `/home` partition and assign to `/` partition?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, memory-usage

I am new in ubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on dual-boot system with Windows 8.1.
I need ubuntu to work with databases that handle large volumes of data. When configuring the system I assign to the partition `/` 150GB size and 150GB to  `/home` partition.

However the `/`partition is getting crowded (there are only 20Gb).

Is there any way to remove space to the `/home` partition and assign to `/` partition?

Comment: Yes. You can resize partitions using applications for editing partitions.  For example [gparted](http://gparted.org/).

Comment: Can you explain me how I can do this step by step?

Comment: Check out this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDgUwWkvuIY).

Answer (score 0):

Generally **yes**. 
You can resize partitions using one of applications for manipulating disk partition tables. Most known such application is [gparted](http://gparted.org/).

There is plenty of text and video tutorials, how to use gparted. For example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDgUwWkvuIY) or [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted).

However there are 2 important things you should be aware of.

- **Backup your data** before resizing partitions.
- It might be more complicated to resize partitions if you have them encrypted (using [cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup)). In that case start with reading [that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) page.